# How can a method that shuffles cards be declared in Java?

Tags: java, methods, return, declaration

This method is intended to shuffle a deck of cards. The current method declaration has a "void" return type and the error "invalid method declaration; return type required" appears when the code is run. What return type can be used instead?

```
public void shuffle()
{
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    
    for(int i; i = 100; i++)
    {
        count = (int)Math.Random() * 52;
        index = (int)Math.Random() * 52;
        
        DeckofCards[count] = DeckofCards[index];
        DeckofCards[index] = DeckofCards[count];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How do you swap the values of two integer variables `a` and `b`?

Comment: I would suggest using a different algorithm - swap the `i`-th card and a card with random index from `i + 1` to 100: `random.nextInt(i + 1, 101)`. You need to create a `Random` instance beforehand: `Random random = new Random()`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the for loop. You **declare** the int `i` but never **initialize**. The condition segment is currently an assignment. You need to initialize and also change the condition.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to initialize the counter `i` and change the assignment in the second portion to a comparison. Second, to swap two variables, you will need to use a temporary variable so the value of the first one is not lost.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    count = (int)Math.Random() * 52;
    index = (int)Math.Random() * 52;
    Card temp = DeckofCards[count];//assuming DeckofCards is an array of Card objects
    DeckofCards[count] = DeckofCards[index];
    DeckofCards[index] = temp;
}
```

Comment: You don't *need*. You *may want* to use a temporary variable.

Comment: @Jack It depends on the type of variables being swapped. I doubt the XOR trick can be applied here.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized `i` in your loop.  And you're not swapping the cards correctly.  But regardless that is not a good way to shuffle cards.

I suggest you do it like this. This will guarantee an excellent shuffle iterating over the list one time.  Cards that have been moved to the end of the list will not be moved again. I presumed that the cards were some type like `Card`.

```
public static void shuffle(DeckOfCards[] v) {
    int count = v.length;
    Random r = new Random();
    while (count > 0) {
       int next = r.nextInt(count);
       Card temp = v[next];
       v[next] = v[--count];
       v[count] = temp;
      }
   }
}
```

You could also put the cards in a `List` and call `Collections.shuffle()`